# MySql : query to format a specific column in database table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one column name phone_number in the database table.Right now the numbers stored in the table are format like ex.+91-852-9689568.I want to format it and just want only digits.
How can i do it in MySql ? I have tried it with using functions like REGEXP but it displays error like function does not exist.And i don't want to use multiple REPLACE.

Comment: guess you are better off with a small `function` to strip the numbers off ;) since you do not want to use two `replace`..although that was the best catch...

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to use `mySql substring`. (As long as the format doesn't change)

```
SELECT concat(SUBSTRING(pNo,2,2), SUBSTRING(pNo,5,3), SUBSTRING(pNo,9,7));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to format via projection only, use `SELECT`, you will only need to use replace twice and no problem with that.

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(columnNAme, '-', ''), '+', '') 
FROM   tableName
```

otherwise, if you want to update the value permanently, use UPDATE

```
UPDATE tableName
SET    columnName = REPLACE(REPLACE(columnNAme, '-', ''), '+', '')
```

Comment: PS : "And i don't want to use multiple REPLACE."

Comment: @TJ- i read that. but i guess its much better that using `substring`. it is much flexible. what if the pattern of the values is not the same? anyway the `OP` has still to choose.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not have a builtin function for pattern-matching and replace.

You'll be better off fetching the whole string back to your application, and then using a more flexible string-manipulation function on it. For instance, preg_replace() in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following and comment please.

```
Select dbo.Regex('\d+',pNo);

Select dbo.Regex('[0-9]+',pNo);
```

Reference on [RUBLAR](http://rubular.com/r/qUyIotCEBa).

So MYSQL is not like Oracle, hence you may just use a [`USer defined Function to get numbers`](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,394717,394909#msg-394909). This could get you going.